# Restful API .Net Core : Static Lookup Table Management. Separate Controller for each table or One generic

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

We need to manage static lookup tables with API, all tables have same structure so creating separate controller for each table or One generic Controller for all end points is better options?

Also We are getting all Lookup Data in one API Call with the Model for each Table in Response Model, so when we need to get the individual data should we create separate endpoint or we can manage this by providing a query parameter **"type"** to populate only specified Model. I was just wondering that can we use query parameter for this functionality? Any industry standard for this?

Comment: Restful was implemnted by .net core webapi by default(but not forced),with the Attribute[ApiController],For your requirement,i think you could create different controllers